# How to use MapReduce on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How to use MapReduce on MongoDB, to refactor the structure of one table and copy the data of the original table to new table? or whatever ways to achieve that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can read it here

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

especially the

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/